# Lightshot Screenshot image preview from the URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've created a support forum where people frequently attach images taken by **Lightshot Screenshot**. They generally add the uploaded URL (like `https://prnt.sc/ujaclu`) to the forum. Basically all the images attached by uploading are previewed to the forum. But from the Lightshot URL, I cannot get any image.

Could anyone help me to parse the Lightshot URL (`https://prnt.sc/ujaclu`) as I can use it to an `src` URL of `<img />` tag using **JavaScript**?

**Note: I didn't get any hint on how to do it. I am completely stuck on it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a solution for the Lightshot image extraction using Javascrit : [LightShot Image Extractor](https://gist.github.com/foyez/0026fcecfd56673db91a5ea4ae10e2c6)

Here is the code:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const axios = require('axios')

/**
 * Extracts the jpg url from a LightShot page
 * lightshot_image('http://prntscr.com/dki21q')
 * http://image.prntscr.com/image/1aaf571d0adf4aa098eb565bbb196af6.png
 */

async function lightshotImageExtractor(url) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    const imgUrl = parseHTML(data)
    return imgUrl
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return null
  }
}

function parseHTML(html) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html)
  const rows = $('.screenshot-image')

  if (rows.length > 0 && rows[0].attribs && rows[0].attribs.src) {
    return rows[0].attribs.src
  }

  return null
}

lightshotImageExtractor('http://prntscr.com/dki21q').then((url) =>
  console.log(url),
)
```

Comment: Can you use the extracted `URL` to any other site skipping the `CORS` problem? I mean  if you want to use the `URL` to the site `https://example.com` then is it okay?

Comment: I also  use this to scrape hacker news data without facing any cors issue... If you want to use this for any other site, you have to change the code... is this solved your problem?

Comment: There is a problem with `https://image.prntscr.com/image/EdCTchd1TLit-Gg1Mtt-pg.png` URL. The server which provides the image doesn't allow to fetch image from another site.

Comment: Ok then that may be different issue with lishtshot site.. but I have tested using this link `<img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/EdCTchd1TLit-Gg1Mtt-pg.png" alt="fetched img" />` from local server... but I didn't face any problem...

Comment: Thanks @Foyez. I will try if this works then I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The link you are trying to use to show the image is not images url. It is url of a page. That's why it is not showing any image.

This is the actual url of the image https://image.prntscr.com/image/EdCTchd1TLit-Gg1Mtt-pg.png

Contact with them and ask them if they can help you with their link decryption.

Comment: I know that. But I need something or some API (if any and anyone uses it) to parse this URL.

Comment: but everyone shares `https://prnt.sc/ujaclu` this URL and is there any way to get the value `ujaclu` => `EdCTchd1TLit-Gg1Mtt-pg`. This is the question.

Comment: Yeah. I see. I already sent an email to them about this. You can send them too. If I get any solution, I will update the replay.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I had sent them email but they are like dead :)